# EXEC sp_executesql with variable numbers of parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-executesql

I am trying to implement a user customizable search and finally I got to the SQL part. The user can select a variable number of criteria and I send everything to the stored procedure in a table-valued parameter. I figured out the logic on how to create the sql string, but I am stuck at the part where I send the parameter. A pseudo code example would be :

```
foreach parameter in the table-valued parameter
   SqlString = SqlString + '@parameter'
   ParamList= ParamList + '@parameter'

EXEC sp_executesql SqlString , ParamList, ???
```

My question is how do I set up the parameters, when I don't know how many they are?

Answer (score 0):

Populate your table variable with Column Name, Operator, and Value.  Then you can iterate through it and build a where clause.  Then append the where clause to your sqlstring parameter.

```
Declare @WhereClause varchar(max)
set @WhereClause = 'Where 1=1'
```

... then loop through the table ...

```
Select @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' and ' + ColumnName + ' ' + Operator + ' ' + Value
From @tableVariable
```

Append where clause to the select statement and execute

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SqlString + @WhereClause
```

Comment: That was the main idea, but in order to prevent sql injection I need to add the value as a parameter, not just concatenate it with the main string. And if i do that then I need to add parametersto the Exec commands...